# Can I define non-malleable inputs in a malleable VI?

Tags: labview

Like is in the title, can I have a couple of malleable inputs, and a couple of fixed-type inputs in the same malleable Labview VI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **Types Must Match** primitive which will break the caller if the wired type doesn't match a constant.

Have a single frame in the Type Specialization Structure and a TMM primitive for each of the fixed-type inputs.

[image]

This is not officially supported in LV 2017, but you can find the primitive and the structure inside **vi.lib\Debug Log\Debug Write.vim**.

You can find additional discussion [here](https://lavag.org/topic/20349-types-must-match/#comment-123762).